# Simple exercise on subspace and product topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $\,X:=\big( [ \, 0,+\infty\, [ \, \, \times \, \,[ \, 0 \,, 1\, ]\big)\, \,  \cup \, \,   \big(  ] \, -\infty,0\, ] \, \, \times \, \,\{ \, 0 \,\}\big) \,$ as a topological subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $p_2 :X \, \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be the projection on the second coordinate, Prove that:

1) $p_2$  is an identification (or quotient map).

2) $p_2$ is not open.

3) $p_2$ is closed.

$\mathbf{My \, \,  attempt: }$

For 2) i used the set : $\quad ]\,-1, 1 \, [ \, \, \times \, \, ]\, -1, \, 2 \,[ \,$ that is open in $\mathbb{R}^2\,$ and intersects $X$ in $]\,-1, 0\,] \, \times \, \{0\} \, \, \cup \, \, [\, 0, 1\,[ \, \times\, [\, 0,\,1] \, $
 that has a closed image trough $p_2$. Now my idea was to prove 3) and then use that $p_2$ is closed, continue and surjective to prove 1). To prove 3) i'm using the fact that any closed set in $X$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, has a bounded coordinate along the y-axis, therefore the image trough $p_2$ is compact and so closed in $\mathbb{R}$ (i'm sorry for not being totally clear on this point but it's not in the main scope of why i'm asking this question).

$\mathbf{my \, \,Question: }$ Why is $p_2 $ surjective?

Comment: $p_2 :X \, \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not surjective. Try to solve $p_2(x)=-1.$ But $p_2 :X \, \rightarrow [0,1]$ is surjective.

Comment: So at most i can assert that $p_2: \, X \rightarrow [\,0 , 1\,]  $ is an identification, right?

Comment: Yes. You're right.

Comment: I find the backwards bracket notation really hard to read.

Comment: I mostly use it  when i'm working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to not confuse sets and points  (e.g. the point $(\,0,1\,)$ and the set $]\,0,1\,[\, $ )

Comment: @talkingdog: I understand the logic behind the notation, but have never adapted to it...